# Creating a Data From that would link to an Issue List in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have an Issue List to track some user requests in SharePoint. The Issue list has a default **Add New Issue** Form Option which is perfect for manual entries. What I want to do is, to have a user request form - also through SharePoint, which the users would fill out to raise a request. When requests are submitted, the fields filled out by the users should automatically get populated in the Issue List. The other fields like status, Assigned to, etc. would then be manually filled out by the team. Is this possible in SharePoint ?

Any Help is much appreciated ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a workflow in SharePoint Designer. When an item in the Requests list is created, the workflow will create an item in the Issue list.  Use the action "Create List item", specify the Issue list, then click on the Issue list name in the action, modify each field and set it to the current item's field.